# How to compile Bootstrap SASS for RTL?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-rtl

When compiling the standard version of Bootstrap, I typically compile `node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss`. this will generate the default version of bootstrap as expected.

But, how can I compile it to generate bootstrap.rtl.css?

Comment: May I recommend to use a dedicated SASS library for RTL support - like `rtl-sass` available on npm? It gives you full control on your RTL implementation.